# Is there anything I should be doing to protect my security when opening a port?

Tags: django, localhost, port

I'm new to this, so I apologize if my question is a little too simplistic or I don't have the correct understanding. I can't find anything in the django guide and I'm not sure if the general port information is the same considering what i'm doing with Django.

I'm running a django runserver on '0.0.0.0:8000', which allows me to access the server remotely on another device in the same household.

Is there anything I should be doing to help protect from outside attacks as the port is open?

I believe I read that although this won't grant access to the device running the server, it can leave it vulnerable to issues. But there shouldn't be any sensitive data being transmitted as it's been used to enter data into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have not performed any port forwarding from the internet to the device that you are running your Django server on you are safe. It will only expose the Django web service and realistically locally in your house hopefully you don't have anyone out to get you.

If you only want to be able to access your Django development server locally you can change the command to: `python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000` no one will be able to access it unless they are coming from the same machine.